# Hibernate picking up second previous id value for next sequence

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Here is how Id is configured in my entity class,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "test_data")
    @NamedQuery(name = "TestData.findAll", query = "SELECT t FROM TestData t")
    public class TestData implements Serializable {
    @GenericGenerator(name = "testDataSequenceGenerator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator", parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "test_data_Seq"),
            @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000"), @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1") })
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "testDataSequenceGenerator")
    protected Long id;
    }
```

I persist data into the table implementing **JpaRepository** interface. The incrementing worked fine until I developed a new biz solution where I would need to insert the ID value based on biz needs.

Example: My current top row in Postgres DB is having ID = 1000. Therefore my next would be 1001 as per the generation config I have done in my entity. But with the new enhancement. I am inserting ID = 2000. Since JPA would not allow user-defined ID (I believe it is because of the configuration on ID), I have used native query to execute the same using the EntityManager.

Now doing this; once I run biz workflow that inserts ID based on user input. And later when I am trying to create a new entry, hibernate is incrementing by using the previously created ID,i.e, 1001, instead of 2001.

Is this because of any caching in hibernate? Do I need to update the next value in hibernate. Could you please assist me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your configuration, you're using a sequence to generate ids (`test_data_seq`) without using hibernate sequence value cache. As you set ID = 2000 manually, the sequence's current value isn't being updated. You need to update it manually, e.g. by using [this function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```
SELECT setval('test_data_seq', 2000);
```

In this case, the next generated value should be 2001.

Overall, it's better to avoid setting ids manually if you use sequence generators for it, because there is a high risk to have a collision.

Comment: In that case, let's say. I have performed the above execution. And I would want to insert another ID with a value = 1500. Now I don't want my next id to be 1501. It should be still 2001. Do I need to implement a logic to find a greater value of the Ids or is there any other better way.

Comment: The current sequence value will stay the same (2001) - manually inserted id values don't affect it. You won't have problems if you insert a value that is lower than the current sequence one. About additional logic - you can handle it in several ways (like you said, to find the greater value, also you can insert knowingly low values instead, even negative ones). The better way, as I said, is to avoid manual inserts of ids at all if you use sequences at the same time.